# How to get a XML respose for a api which returns a response entity consisting of a list of object

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, fasterxml

I have written a REST API in spring boot. The API returns a list of object as a response. I am returning a ResponseEntity object from the API's controller class. But the XML output I get is not properly formatted. I am using `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat` library.

The POM file for the Project is:

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>sampleapi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.13.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

My controller class is:

**TestController.java**

```
package com.example.sampleapi.controller;


import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.sampleapi.Entity.Student;
import com.example.sampleapi.Entity.StudentResponse;
import com.example.sampleapi.dao.StudentDAO;


@RestController
public class TestController {
    @Autowired
    private StudentDAO studentDao;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method =RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = {
            MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    public boolean saveAllStudents() {
        return studentDao.saveStudents();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get", method =RequestMethod.GET, produces = {
            MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<StudentResponse> getAllStudents() {
        List<Student> studentList = studentDao.getAllStudent();

        int count = studentList.size();

        StudentResponse studentResponse = new StudentResponse();
        studentResponse.setStudentList(studentList);
        studentResponse.setCount(count);

        return new ResponseEntity<StudentResponse>(studentResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

My DAO class is:

**StudentDAOImpl.java**

```
package com.example.sampleapi.dao.impl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.sampleapi.Entity.Student;
import com.example.sampleapi.dao.StudentDAO;


@Repository
public class StudentDAOImpl implements StudentDAO {

    private List<Student> studentDetails = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public boolean saveStudents() {
        Student student1 = new Student();
        student1.setName("A");
        student1.setAge(23);
        student1.setMarks(100);

        Student student2 = new Student();
        student2.setName("B");
        student2.setAge(25);
        student2.setMarks(90);

        Student student3 = new Student();
        student3.setName("C");
        student3.setAge(19);
        student3.setMarks(95);

        studentDetails.add(student1);
        studentDetails.add(student2);
        studentDetails.add(student3);
        if(studentDetails.size() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<Student> getAllStudent() {
        return studentDetails;
    }

}
```

The Student Entity class is as follows:

**Student.java**

```
package com.example.sampleapi.Entity;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlRootElement
public class Student {

    private String name;

    private int age;

    private double marks;

    public Student() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public double getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    public void setMarks(double marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", marks=" + marks + "]";
    }

}
```

The Response class is as follows:

**StudentResponse.java**

```
package com.example.sampleapi.Entity;

import java.util.List;

public class StudentResponse {

    int count;

    List<Student> studentList;

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public List<Student> getStudentList() {
        return studentList;
    }

    public void setStudentList(List<Student> studentList) {
        this.studentList = studentList;
    }
```

}

The Xml response for the `/get` RequestMapping is :

```
<StudentResponse>
  <count>3</count>
  <studentList>
    <studentList>
      <name>A</name>
      <age>23</age>
      <marks>100.0</marks>
    </studentList>
    <studentList>
      <name>B</name>
      <age>25</age>
      <marks>90.0</marks>
    </studentList>
    <studentList>
      <name>C</name>
      <age>19</age>
      <marks>95.0</marks>
    </studentList>
  </studentList>
</StudentResponse>
```

Why the Student objects inside the list are coming as `<studentList></studentList>`, it should be `<student></student>` instead?

The XML format I am expecting is:

```
<StudentResponse>
  <count>3</count>
  <studentList>
    <student>
      <name>A</name>
      <age>23</age>
      <marks>100.0</marks>
    </student>
    <student>
      <name>B</name>
      <age>25</age>
      <marks>90.0</marks>
    </student>
    <student>
      <name>C</name>
      <age>19</age>
      <marks>95.0</marks>
    </student>
  </studentList>
</StudentResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the outer `studentList` is that that is the property name of that list in the `StudentResponse`.

The reason you get the inner `studentList` is that

> When a collection property is annotated just with @XmlElement [as is assumed in Spring Boot when you don't have any annotation], each item in the collection will be wrapped by an element.
>   [Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlList.html)

You'll need to put annotations on your Java classes to get the result you want, in this case something like [shown here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html)

```
public class Customer {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="studentList")
    @XmlElement(name="student")
    private List<Student> studentList;

}
```

Comment: I have tried the solution but it seems that the annotations are not working
`@XmlRootElement
  public class StudentResponse {
 @XmlElement(name = "numbers")
 int count;
 
 @XmlElementWrapper(name="student")
 @XmlElement(name="student")
 List<Student> studentList;

 public int getCount() {
  return count;
 }

 public void setCount(int count) {
  this.count = count;
 }
 
 public List<Student> getStudentList() {
  return studentList;
 }

 public void setStudentList(List<Student> studentList) {
  this.studentList = studentList;
 }
 
 
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "student")
public class Student {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is also not working `This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.` Output is same and the above line also coming in the browser window